# React routes issues with ngix when pages reload

Tags: reactjs, nginx, routes

I am working on a project that authenticates a user through a login page and then the user enters a page with a sidebar menu that navigates him through the different pages of his account. The thing is, when a page reloads locally, everything works perfectly and no errors occur. Yet, on the server there is an issue that makes any page falls and shows 404 error whenever it reloads as shown below :

[image]

Here is how I set the routes for my sidebar :

```
let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();

    const sideBar = [
        { id: 0, name: "Dashboard", icon: dashboard, path: `${url}/`, exact: true, component: Dashboard },
        { id: 0, name: "Payments", icon: payments, path: `${url}/payments`, component: Payments },
        { id: 1, name: "Leads", icon: leads, path: `${url}/leads`, component: Leads },
        { id: 2, name: "Orders", icon: orders, path: `${url}/orders`, component: Orders },
        { id: 3, name: "Customers", icon: customers, path: `${url}/customers`, component: Customers },
        { id: 4, name: "Profile", icon: profile, path: `${url}/profile`, component: Profile },
        { id: 5, name: "Branches", icon: profile, path: `${url}/branches`, component: Branches },
        { id: 6, name: "Administration", icon: administration0, path: `${url}/administration`, component: Administration },
    ];

const RenderSidebar = () => {
        return (
            sideBar.map((route, index) =>
                <Nav style={{ display: "flex" }} className={`${route.name.toLowerCase()}`}>
                    {route.name === "Reports" ?
                        <NavItem className="sublink-wrapper">
                            <NavLink to={`${route.path}`}>
                                <ListGroupItem key={index}><img className={`${isToggleSideBar ? "toggled" : ""} icon-img`} src={route.icon} />{route.name}</ListGroupItem>
                            </NavLink>
                            <div className="sublinks">
                                <NavLink to={`${route.path}/ordersanalysis`}>
                                    <ListGroupItem key={index}><img className={`${isToggleSideBar ? "toggled" : ""} icon-img`} src={ordersAnalysis} />Orders Analysis</ListGroupItem>
                                </NavLink>
                                <NavLink to={`${route.path}/customersanalysis`}>
                                    <ListGroupItem key={index}><img className={`${isToggleSideBar ? "toggled" : ""} icon-img`} src={customersAnalysis} />Customer Analysis</ListGroupItem>
                                </NavLink>
                                <NavLink to={`${route.path}/paymentanalysis`}>
                                    <ListGroupItem key={index}><img className={`${isToggleSideBar ? "toggled" : ""} icon-img`} src={paymentAnalysis} />Payment Analysis</ListGroupItem>
                                </NavLink>
                            </div>
                        </NavItem>
                        :
                        (route.name === "Profile" ?
                            <NavItem className="sublink-wrapper">
                                <NavLink to={`${route.path}`} onClick={() => {
                                    setToggled(!isToggled);
                                    setLink("sublink-toggled");
                                }}>
                                    <ListGroupItem key={index}><img className={`${isToggleSideBar ? "toggled" : ""} icon-img`} src={route.icon} />{route.name}</ListGroupItem>
                                </NavLink>
                                <div className={`sublinks ${isToggled && isSublink}`}>
                                    <NavLink to={`${route.path}/businessdetails`}>
                                        <ListGroupItem key={index}><img className={`${isToggleSideBar ? "toggled" : ""} icon-img`} src={businessDetails} />Business Details</ListGroupItem>
                                    </NavLink>
                                    <NavLink to={`${route.path}/companydocuments`}>
                                        <ListGroupItem key={index}><img className={`${isToggleSideBar ? "toggled" : ""} icon-img`} src={companyDocuments} />Company Documents</ListGroupItem>
                                    </NavLink>
                                    <NavLink to={`${route.path}/products&services`}>
                                        <ListGroupItem key={index}><img className={`${isToggleSideBar ? "toggled" : ""} icon-img`} src={companyDocuments} />Producst & Services</ListGroupItem>
                                    </NavLink>
                                    <NavLink to={`${route.path}/workinghours`}>
                                        <ListGroupItem key={index}><img className={`${isToggleSideBar ? "toggled" : ""} icon-img`} src={workingHours} />Working Hours</ListGroupItem>
                                    </NavLink>
                                    <NavLink to={`${route.path}/discounts`}>
                                        <ListGroupItem key={index}><img className={`${isToggleSideBar ? "toggled" : ""} icon-img`} src={coupons} />Discounts & Coupons</ListGroupItem>
                                    </NavLink>

                                </div>
                            </NavItem>
                            :
                            <NavLink to={route.path}>
                                <ListGroupItem key={index}><img className={`${isToggleSideBar ? "toggled" : ""} icon-img`} src={route.icon} />{route.name}</ListGroupItem>
                            </NavLink>)
                    }
                </Nav>
            ))
    }
```

This is a function that renders my sidebar and I declare the routes below to navigate through the different routes as following :

```
    {sideBar.map((route, index) => (
                                    <Route
                                        key={index}
                                        path={route.path}
                                        exact={route.exact}
                                        component={route.component} />
                                ))}
```

Is there anything that I need to change here so that this error ends. I have spent weeks on this problem and I found no solution.

Comment: try to modify default configuration file in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default to `location / {
  try_files $uri /index.html;
}`

Comment: Isn't there anything that I can do in React to fix this issue? @Alex

Comment: Try your code at codesandbox.io , if receive same error it could be from React

Comment: @Alex this error doesn't occur on localhost at all. It always occurs on the server. And how could I fix the problem if it is in React and what could it be?

Comment: because you mentioned always occurred on the server, I think its not from React.try with codesandbox and put the link here

Comment: @Alex Yes it never happens locally. I will put it on Sandbox and check if it is gonna work or not.